Forcing postgres planner to prioritize simpler queries over computationally heavy ones
I've got a scenario where postgres is doing a huge amount of extra work.
I'm trying to query a view that is computationally very heavy.  However, I never intend to return large sets of data from it, so I figured it would probably be ok...
However, when I try to filter it, it seems like PG planner is doing a full materialization of the view and only then applying filtering.
SELECT * FROM record_view ORDER BY last_updated desc LIMIT 1

So I thought maybe I could force it to run more performant b
SELECT * FROM record_view WHERE id IN (
  SELECT record_id FROM record_field GROUP BY record_id ORDER BY MAX(updated_at) desc LIMIT 1
)

It takes about 6x longer than if I were to just run the two queries sequentially.
I've even tried adding very specific indexes to try and get it to prioritze the first query:
CREATE INDEX idx_record_field_recordid_updatedat_desc
    ON record_field (record_id, updated_at DESC);

Details
-- Object Definitions
create table "public"."object" (
    "id" text not null,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    "label" text
);

-- Field Definitions

create table "public"."field" (
    "id" text not null,
    "object_id" text not null,
    "label" text not null,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    "type" text not null default 'string'::text,
    "is_unique" boolean not null default false
);

alter table "public"."object" enable row level security;
alter table "public"."field" enable row level security;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "object_pkey" ON public.object USING btree (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX field_pkey ON public.field USING btree (id, object_id);


alter table "public"."object" add constraint "object_pkey" PRIMARY KEY using index "object_pkey";
alter table "public"."field" add constraint "field_pkey" PRIMARY KEY using index "field_pkey";

alter table "public"."field" add constraint "field_object_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE not valid;
alter table "public"."field" validate constraint "field_object_id_fkey";

create table "public"."record" (
    "id" uuid not null default gen_random_uuid(),
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    "object_id" text not null
);


alter table "public"."record" enable row level security;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX record_pkey ON public.record USING btree (id, object_id);

create table "public"."record_field" (
    "field_id" text not null,
    "object_id" text not null,
    "record_id" uuid not null,
    "updated_at" timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    "data" jsonb
);

alter table "public"."record_field" enable row level security;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX record_field_pkey ON public.record_field USING btree (field_id, object_id, record_id);

alter table "public"."record" add constraint "record_pkey" PRIMARY KEY using index "record_pkey";

alter table "public"."record_field" add constraint "record_field_pkey" PRIMARY KEY using index "record_field_pkey";

alter table "public"."record" add constraint "record_object_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE not valid;

alter table "public"."record" validate constraint "record_object_id_fkey";

alter table "public"."record_field" add constraint "record_field_field_id_object_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (field_id, object_id) REFERENCES field(id, object_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE not valid;

alter table "public"."record_field" validate constraint "record_field_field_id_object_id_fkey";

alter table "public"."record_field" add constraint "record_field_object_id_record_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (object_id, record_id) REFERENCES record(object_id, id) not valid;

alter table "public"."record_field" validate constraint "record_field_object_id_record_id_fkey";

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "public"."record_view" 
WITH (security_invoker = true) AS
SELECT 
    rf.object_id,
    rf.record_id AS id,
    json_object_agg(f.id, rf.data) AS data,
    MAX(rf.updated_at) AS last_updated
FROM 
    record_field rf
JOIN 
    field f 
    ON rf.field_id = f.id 
    AND rf.object_id = f.object_id
GROUP BY 
    rf.object_id, 
    rf.record_id;

Explain Results
explain analyse SELECT * FROM record_view WHERE id IN (
  SELECT record_id FROM record_field GROUP BY record_id ORDER BY max(updated_at) desc LIMIT 1
)

| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                           |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| Hash Join  (cost=430728.66..482205.64 rows=562 width=63) (actual time=2267.232..2879.726 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                             |
|   Hash Cond: (rf.record_id = "ANY_subquery".record_id)                                                                                                                               |
|   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=296770.54..346821.66 rows=112444 width=63) (actual time=1468.243..2332.244 rows=112011 loops=1)                                                           |
|         Group Key: rf.object_id, rf.record_id                                                                                                                                        |
|         Planned Partitions: 256  Batches: 257  Memory Usage: 3113kB  Disk Usage: 245328kB                                                                                            |
|         ->  Hash Join  (cost=20.25..48817.12 rows=1779038 width=86) (actual time=0.041..598.819 rows=1779038 loops=1)                                                                |
|               Hash Cond: ((rf.field_id = f.id) AND (rf.object_id = f.object_id))                                                                                                     |
|               ->  Seq Scan on record_field rf  (cost=0.00..39456.38 rows=1779038 width=63) (actual time=0.012..254.655 rows=1779038 loops=1)                                         |
|               ->  Hash  (cost=14.10..14.10 rows=410 width=64) (actual time=0.018..0.021 rows=25 loops=1)                                                                             |
|                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB                                                                                                                    |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on field f  (cost=0.00..14.10 rows=410 width=64) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=25 loops=1)                                                         |
|   ->  Hash  (cost=133958.11..133958.11 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=538.110..539.750 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                |
|         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                 |
|         ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=133958.10..133958.11 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=538.105..539.745 rows=1 loops=1)                                               |
|               ->  Limit  (cost=133958.10..133958.10 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=538.103..539.577 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                   |
|                     ->  Sort  (cost=133958.10..134239.21 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=538.094..539.562 rows=1 loops=1)                                                         |
|                           Sort Key: (max(record_field.updated_at)) DESC                                                                                                              |
|                           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                                  |
|                           ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=104908.23..133395.88 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=497.679..531.461 rows=112011 loops=1)                           |
|                                 Group Key: record_field.record_id                                                                                                                    |
|                                 ->  Gather Merge  (cost=104908.23..131147.00 rows=224888 width=24) (actual time=497.673..515.269 rows=115025 loops=1)                                |
|                                       Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                             |
|                                       Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                            |
|                                       ->  Sort  (cost=103908.21..104189.32 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=481.532..484.165 rows=38342 loops=3)                                   |
|                                             Sort Key: record_field.record_id                                                                                                         |
|                                             Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3654kB                                                                                                   |
|                                             Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3332kB                                                                                        |
|                                             Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3556kB                                                                                        |
|                                             ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=82357.15..92168.30 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=452.259..458.555 rows=38342 loops=3)              |
|                                                   Group Key: record_field.record_id                                                                                                  |
|                                                   Planned Partitions: 4  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4881kB                                                                            |
|                                                   Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4369kB                                                                                        |
|                                                   Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4625kB                                                                                        |
|                                                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on record_field  (cost=0.00..29078.66 rows=741266 width=24) (actual time=0.296..355.722 rows=593013 loops=3) |
| Planning Time: 11.046 ms                                                                                                                                                             |
| Execution Time: 2919.026 ms                                                                                                                                                          |

Queries on their own
explain analyse SELECT record_id FROM record_field GROUP BY record_id ORDER BY MAX(updated_at) desc LIMIT 1

| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                         |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| Limit  (cost=133958.10..133958.10 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=547.848..550.734 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                   |
|   ->  Sort  (cost=133958.10..134239.21 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=547.846..550.732 rows=1 loops=1)                                                         |
|         Sort Key: (max(updated_at)) DESC                                                                                                                           |
|         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                                  |
|         ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=104908.23..133395.88 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=499.786..542.183 rows=112011 loops=1)                           |
|               Group Key: record_id                                                                                                                                 |
|               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=104908.23..131147.00 rows=224888 width=24) (actual time=499.776..525.336 rows=115000 loops=1)                                |
|                     Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                             |
|                     Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                            |
|                     ->  Sort  (cost=103908.21..104189.32 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=485.506..489.133 rows=38333 loops=3)                                   |
|                           Sort Key: record_id                                                                                                                      |
|                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3579kB                                                                                                   |
|                           Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3486kB                                                                                        |
|                           Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3476kB                                                                                        |
|                           ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=82357.15..92168.30 rows=112444 width=24) (actual time=467.843..473.231 rows=38333 loops=3)              |
|                                 Group Key: record_id                                                                                                               |
|                                 Planned Partitions: 4  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4881kB                                                                            |
|                                 Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4625kB                                                                                        |
|                                 Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4625kB                                                                                        |
|                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on record_field  (cost=0.00..29078.66 rows=741266 width=24) (actual time=0.114..380.557 rows=593013 loops=3) |
| Planning Time: 2.946 ms                                                                                                                                            |
| Execution Time: 554.166 ms                                                                                                                                         |


explain analyse SELECT * FROM record_view WHERE id IN ('91381946-82fd-480b-a910-16e5e8ae0461')

| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                  |
| ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| GroupAggregate  (cost=84.26..84.66 rows=16 width=63) (actual time=8.467..8.515 rows=1 loops=1)                                                              |
|   Group Key: rf.object_id, rf.record_id                                                                                                                     |
|   ->  Sort  (cost=84.26..84.30 rows=16 width=86) (actual time=8.174..8.224 rows=16 loops=1)                                                                 |
|         Sort Key: rf.object_id                                                                                                                              |
|         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB                                                                                                                |
|         ->  Hash Join  (cost=67.69..83.94 rows=16 width=86) (actual time=8.064..8.127 rows=16 loops=1)                                                      |
|               Hash Cond: ((f.id = rf.field_id) AND (f.object_id = rf.object_id))                                                                            |
|               ->  Seq Scan on field f  (cost=0.00..14.10 rows=410 width=64) (actual time=3.815..3.820 rows=25 loops=1)                                      |
|               ->  Hash  (cost=67.45..67.45 rows=16 width=63) (actual time=1.477..1.486 rows=16 loops=1)                                                     |
|                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB                                                                                           |
|                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on record_field rf  (cost=4.55..67.45 rows=16 width=63) (actual time=0.449..0.476 rows=16 loops=1)                 |
|                           Recheck Cond: (record_id = '91381946-82fd-480b-a910-16e5e8ae0461'::uuid)                                                          |
|                           Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                                                              |
|                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on record_field_record_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.55 rows=16 width=0) (actual time=0.436..0.443 rows=16 loops=1) |
|                                 Index Cond: (record_id = '91381946-82fd-480b-a910-16e5e8ae0461'::uuid)                                                      |
| Planning Time: 4.332 ms                                                                                                                                     |
| Execution Time: 8.961 ms                                                                                                                                    |


I tried a MATERIALIZED CTE and it's still slow... Maybe because the queries are running in parallel instead of waiting for the results of the filtered set to come back?

A query with a materialized CTE is still entirely planned up front.  The result of the CTE is not known at the time, and so can't be used while planning.  It might be nice if there were a SUPER MATERIALIZED option which got around this, but there isn't.

what is the output of explain (generic_plan) SELECT * FROM record_view WHERE id IN ($1)?   generic_plan was new in v16.

I added the relevant create table statement and constraints (I know the schema is crazy, this isn't a production system, but an experiment/learning exercise to see if I can create a fully
"end user defined" schema) that is reasonably performant, access controlled (RLS & CLS) and type safe.

@jjanes I'm using supabase and I just realized it's stuck on v15.  Sounds like there have been some pretty significant performance upgrades in 16 & 17, I wonder if that alone would fix things.

From my own experimentation, this is a limitation in the planner which persists in the newest versions.  The generic_plan would be nice to nail it down more definitively, but I now think it wouldn't do much more than that.

Although the planner "knows" that your subquery with LIMIT 1 will only return 1 row, it apparently doesn't know it with enough certainty to build a plan whose correctness depends on this fact.
You can get around this limitation by changing to equality, using id = (subquery) instead of id IN (subquery).  The only difference between these might be if the subquery should happen to return 0 rows, although I think it would be the same in that case as well.
Note the subquery itself is also gratuitously complex and slow.
SELECT record_id FROM record_field ORDER BY updated_at desc LIMIT 1

should give identical results as
SELECT record_id FROM record_field GROUP BY record_id ORDER BY MAX(updated_at) desc LIMIT 1

But the first one should be faster in general, and far faster if there is a btree index leading with updated_at.

ya... I realized group by wasn't needed after posting this, but didn't want to update all the query plans and it still wasn't making any difference.
Changing IN to = does seem to cause it to prioritize the queries correctly now... Unfortunately, what I really need is to be able to get ~100 results matching different criteria so I'm still unfortunately in the same boat.
But since you technically answered the question as it was asked, I'll go ahead and mark this.  It doesn't seem like there is really a solution short of something like this https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan.
